# How to close the browser using C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When my Login button is clicked, if the login was successful I'd like to close the browser.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
 if (isAuthenticated)
{
// close the browser
}
}
```

I'm not using AJAX so this happens on code behind.

How to send a command (or a javascript call) to the browser to close itself using C# and perhaps using Response... object?

thanks,

UPDATE on the Answer (it closes without warning):

```
const string scriptKey = "closeBrowser";
            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptKey))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), scriptKey, "javascript:setTimeout('parent.Shadowbox.close();', 1000);", true);
            }
```

Comment: Why should a website be able to close my browser? Under certain circumstances(after opening it from js for example) you might be allowed to close a tab, but closing the whole browser should be impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following can be ran server side to add `window.close()` javascript method to your client script. However, the results of this will depend on your browser.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CloseScript", "window.close();", true);
```

Comment: thanks. do you have any solution for the browser warning message? I tried setting the window.opener=self but didn't make any change.

Comment: I don't think there is any solution for this. The browser puts in this warning message to prevent the scripts from being able to automatically close the browser.

Comment: if the browser has opened the new window, it should be able to close it though.

Comment: I have a question that may help.  Since you cannot stop the popup warning message, are you able to modify the message/buttons on the warning message?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force the browser to completely shut down. From the page, you can try

```
window.close();
```

(in JavaScript), but depending on the browser and the situation that may be ignored. If it works, it'll close just the window/tab housing that code.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks its not a good idea to close the browser. Users would rather be more of irritated whenever this happens.

Answer (score 1):

if you opened the window with javascript like

```
var popup = window.open(....)
```

you could execute `popup.close();` with javascript

Closing a whole window/browser isn't possible as far as i know